# Android - TextView alignment for random text

Tags: android, textview, text-justify

I am developing an app. In that I am getting data from webservice and I am inserting it in `TextView`. But, the alignment of the textview is getting scrambled. Please check the image.

First 3 rows(black colored) is in proper order, from the 4th it is scrambled. I googled on it so many times but not getting the exact solution as I wanted.

[image]

**XML Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="70dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
>

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/schedule_1_textView_day_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="KKR"
        android:layout_weight="1.5"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/Black"            
        android:textSize="7sp"
        />        

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/schedule_1_textView_matchno"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="10"
        android:layout_weight="1.5"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:textSize="7sp"
        />        

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/schedule_1_textView_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="6"
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:textSize="7sp"
        />   

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/schedule_1_textView_team1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="4"
        android:textSize="7sp"
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        />       

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/schedule_1_textView_team2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"          
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:textSize="7sp"
        />       

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/schedule_1_textView_venue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="6"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:textSize="7sp"
        /> 

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/schedule_1_textView_blank"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="B"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:textSize="6sp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        /> 


 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Set everywhere layout_width to `"0"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

You forget to add `android:layout_weight="1"` for below two `TextView` Use `android:singleLine="true"` for all `TextView`

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/schedule_1_textView_venue"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="6"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textColor="@color/Black"
    android:textSize="7sp"
    /> 

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/schedule_1_textView_blank"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="B"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:textColor="@color/Black"
    android:textSize="6sp"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    />
```

Answer (score 1):

you might wanna assigh `android:layout_weight` property to the `TextView`s like:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/schedule_1_textView_venue"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="6"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textColor="@color/Black"
    android:textSize="7sp" />
```

you will need to assign **weight** according to your requirement. i.e for bigger views you want to assign higher values.

**[EDIT]** and for the last `TextView` you may want to set `android:layout_gravity="center|right"` and `android:layout_gravity="center|left"` for the first for the **text alignment** for the rest you should use `android:layout_gravity="center"`

Comment: that may be because your text contains extra spaces. you can fix that by using `.trim()` method the remove extra white-spaces in the beginning and at the end of the text.

Answer (score 0):

Add gravity to your `TextView` like:

```
android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
```

change gravity to left, right or center as you need...

Comment: i feel that you are getting the space for your data, better try to trim them before adding to the TextView...

Answer (score 0):

have you tried adding weight to schedule_1_textView_venue?

Comment: Yes. But still same problem

Comment: You should try using a TableLayout instead of a LinearLayout then, the columns should align your textviews

Answer (score 0):

It's a little more work, but did you try using `TableLayout`? [This](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-user-interface-design-table-layouts--mobile-4788) is very useful tutorial that can help you organizing the correct order of views.

EDIT: I think i know what causes the mismatch of the `TextViews`. It comes from the different length of the values in your last column named **VENUE**. Take for example the values **HYDEBARAD**  and **DELHI** - the first one is much longer than the second which makes all the `TextViews` on the row to go left. I am sure that if you put identical `padding` to the `TextViews` you will align them. For example: take your `TextViews` in **MATCH** column and write the following: `myTextView.setPadding(40, 0, 0, 0)` (`padding` on the left side) this will put them exactly in a straight row. Do the same with the rest `TextViews` with the proper `padding` value, take into consideration the length of the values in the other columns... It is a little bit tricky though. :)

Comment: @Mitesh Did you try my solution? (: